# Some functions not appearing on Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to test some functions on my code, and with remix after I deploy a contract, i can see most of the functions but others don't appear. And i need to test all the functions in my code to be able to see if they are working properly.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
contract owned {
    address public owner;
constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }
contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 2;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
// This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    
    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);
/**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }
/**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }
/**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }
/**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

contract cryptealo is owned, TokenERC20 {
uint256 public sellPrice;
uint256 public buyPrice;
mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);
/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}
/* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);               // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }
/// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }
    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }
    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }
/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
    }
/// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        address myAddress = this;
        require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

this is my complete code but out of the code the functions below this :

```
contract cryptealo is owned, TokenERC20 {
```

are not appearing in Remix as functions that i can test.

[image]

as you can see, its not showing the functions _transfer, MintToken, FreezeAccount,SetPrices,buy,sell.

These functions are not appearing, for some reasons i do not know of, is it because  of the ownership, i am new to solidity and i couln't find anything on the web so maybe here i can find an answer. The enviroment i am using for reference is remix and ganache, all the functions showing in the picture works fine, but i need to also test the ones of mintToken, SetPrice etc to see if they are working properly. But I really have no clue why they are not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its not showing the functions _transfer, MintToken,
> FreezeAccount,SetPrices,buy,sell.

It is not showing because these functions are placed in the `cryptealo` contract, while you deployed and call the `TokenERC20` contract. So the mentioned functions are unavailable for that contract.

You can have more contracts in one `.sol` file, but these contracts won't see each other simply by being stored in the same file.

Comment: ok so do you recommend me adding them to the same contract or just make a call function to call the other contract?

Comment: @alexschobel Exactly. Make a call function in your contract which calls the desired function. Maybe if there is an interface for cryptealo contract which is already deployed, using the interface can be an option too. But yes, the point is that you have to call the function from another function.